# JQuery transition animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, setinterval

This program randomly selects two employees from a json-object `Employees` array, `winnerPos` is already defined.

For better user experience I programmed these functions to change pictures one by one. The animation stops when the randomly selected person is shown on the screen.

The `slideThrough` function will be triggered when the `start` button is pressed.

```
function slideThrough() {
    counter = 0;
    start = true;

    clearInterval(picInterval);
    picInterval = setInterval(function () {
        changePicture();
    }, 500);
}   

function changePicture() {
    if (start) {                
        if (counter > winnerPos) {
            setWinner();
            start = false;
            killInterval();
        } else {
            var employee = Employees[counter];

            winnerPic.fadeOut(200, function () {
                this.src = 'img/' + employee.image;
                winnerName.html(employee.name);
                $(this).fadeIn(300);
            });              

            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the animation doesn't work smoothly. At first it works, but not perfect. The second time the transition happens in an irregular way, i.e. different speed and fadeIn/fadeOut differs from picture to picture.

Could anyone help me to fine-tune the transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using `setInterval()` and add a function to the call to `.fadeIn()` that starts the animation of the next picture.

It would look like this:

```
function changePicture(pos) {
    pos = pos || 0;
    if (pos <= winnerPos) {
        var employee = Employees[pos];

        winnerPic.fadeOut(200, function() {
            this.src = 'img/' + employee.image;
            winnerName.html(employee.name);
            $(this).fadeIn(300, function() {
                changePicture(pos + 1);
            });
        });
    } else {
        setWinner();
    }
}
```

To start the animation, you call `changePicture()` without any arguments, like this.

```
changePicture();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ha7brc1a/1/)